# Issue with passing of variables from Fortran DLL to main program

Tags: visual-studio, dll, fortran

I am trying to pass variables (real, integer and double precision etc) from a main program to a DLL and back. I am having some problem when passing variables with data type ‘real’.  For example, a variable ‘X’  is defined as real (8) in the DLL project (x=3.0). This variable must go to the main program. ‘X’ is defined as a real(8) in the main program also. But when passing the variable, it is showing a different value for the variable ‘x’ (x= 5.307579804306449D-315) in the main program. I have kept the data type of X same in both the DLL and the main program. I am not able to figure out the issue in passing the variable.

Comment: Were the DLL and the main program compiled using the same compiler?

Comment: Yes. They are compiled using the same compiler

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Also check what happens when you don't use a dll but link everything statically.